# Remove par(fill)skip from KOMA afterskip

Tags: koma-script, parskip

My document contains pages where the `\parskip` has been stretched. A consequence of this is that the text below section titles is too far away from the text which follows it. How can I make the section titles a constant distance away from the following paragraph?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[top=80mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}


\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  beforeskip= 0.5\baselineskip plus 2\baselineskip minus 0.1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=\parskip]{section}

\setparsizes{0em}{0.1\baselineskip plus 1\baselineskip}{0.5em plus 1fil} 

\newcommand{\lsec}{%
\section{Small sec}
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par}

\newcommand{\msec}{%
\section{Medium sec}
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\par}

\begin{document}
\lsec\lsec\lsec\msec\lsec\lsec
\end{document}
```

[image]

That is, the AAAs should be equally distant from each heading, though the paragraphs may be unequally spaced.

I tried changing `afterskip=1sp`, but this still leaves the `\parskip` or `parfillskip` value (I can't tell which is which from the `cls` file.)

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `\setparsizes{0em}{0.1\baselineskip plus 1\baselineskip}{0.5em plus 1fil}`. Then you have a really small par skip (`.1\baselineskip`) with a large glue (`1\baselineskip`). So there is a big difference between stretched and non stretched par skips. Maybe you can decrease the glue to `.1\baselineskip`. Note that \section itself uses a `\par` command and inserts a par skip. With `afterskip=\parskip` the glue is inserted twice.

Comment: The extreme values were just to demonstrate a MWE. My document does use setparsizes but with more plausible values. However I found it hard to make a MWE with those values.

Comment: You can try `\usepackage{xpatch}\xapptocmd{\sectionlinesformat}{\vspace*{-\parskip}}{}{\PatchFailed}`

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: @Johannes_B : esdd's comment answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the following patch appears to solve the problem:

```
% Removes glue around section titles. 
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\sectionlinesformat}{\vspace*{-\parskip}}{}{\PatchFailed}
```

Comment: you can accept own answer. however this will not increase your reputation points :-)